# Can CSS Media Query be used in the same as bootstrap sizing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am refactoring a page to use media queries instead of writing for each potential size, and my question is, when you are using Media Query, is it possible to set a single size, and then it work like bootstrap, where setting XS will affect sm, md, lg or does it have to be defined at each level?

Example:

```
 @media screen and (max-width:767px){
    .smallDevices {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .ScreenStyle {
        height: 914px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .smallFixFooter {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: `(max-width:767px)` means **EVERYTHING** `767px` wide and higher **will get** affected. *Everything that is less that `767px` **will not** be affected*. Also, using fixed `width` and `height` values without following them up with `max-width` and `max-height` values **kills responsiveness**

Comment: Is it feasible to just refactor your code to use bootstrap?

Comment: @DavidJones Not exactly, I had initially attempted to do that, but ended up with issues in sizing proportions. That is why I went to media query

Comment: There's a typo in my comment and it's too late to edit, I meant to write `(min-width:767px)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set single size for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Pseudo-BNF)

Something like

```
@media (min-width: 123px) {}
```

this will apply when screen size is 123px or greiter

Comment: Thank you very much, this provided some clarity for the situation, I was not sure if I set a single size, if it could work all the way up. This way, I can remove a great deal of bloat.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, if you set an @media query for default (classless / catch-all) elements, this will effect everything. You then modify the rules you need on a per class basis.

Comment: You don't need media queries to tell that all `p` has padding 5px and all `p.extra` has 10px padding

Comment: @Justinas - You do if that extra padding only kicks in below 767px, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has `media query` to define `div` sizes at specified screen sizes. Using media queries you tell your `css` changes to occur. If u study the bootstrap css, you see they used `media queries` depending on each `col` size. Study the codes and you'll understand better.